# python update dictionary with dictionary in loop

Tags: python

I am trying to update a dictionary with an other dictionary in a loop

```
    mainDict = {}
    for index in range(3):
        tempDict = {}
        tempDict['a'] = 1
        tempDict['b'] = 2
        mainDict.update(tempDict)
```

Output:

```
>>> print mainDict
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

What I am expecting is:

```
{{'a': 1, 'b': 2},{'a': 1, 'b': 2},{'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

Any suggestions please. Thanks.

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid Python data structure. A dict without keys? A set of dicts (not possible)?

Comment: That is not even a dictionary

Comment: Do you want a list of dicts as output? like `[{'a': 1, 'b': 2},{'a': 1, 'b': 2},{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]`. Why are using `update` for this at all? `[{'a': 1, 'b': 2} for i in range(3)]`?

Comment: Or a set of dicts? But the contents are not unique.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are key-value pairs. In your expected output there is no dictionary. Either you want a `list`, and in this case use:

```
main_list = []
for (...)
    main_list.append(temp_dict)
```

or add keys in the loop:

```
mainDict = {}
for index in range(3):
    tempDict = {}
    tempDict['a'] = 1
    tempDict['b'] = 2
    mainDict[index] = tempDict
```

Comment: In the second example isn't `index` enough? Why you need another variable `key`?

Answer (score 0):

As others commented in the comments section, python dictionaries keys must be unique. Quoting from python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of *key: value* pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)

**Possible solution**: Create a `list` instead of a `dict` to store the dictionaries.